# Print If Statement in VBE Console + casting variables in

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple question. Is it possible to test if statements directly in the VBE console?

One can make simple mathematical computations and access objects etc. But I've not seen an example of using an If statement.

I was testing the following: ? If Date > "MyDate"

Comment: If statements are branching structures.  Are you just looking for a true/false for an expression in the immediate window?

Comment: This is done in the Immediate Window. You can not only test various statements with using "?" mark in front, but also assign values to variables, output to sheets, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean expressions will evaluate in the immediate window - just leave the "If" off:

```
?Date > CDate("1/1/2010")
True
```

Note that you can also use any of the type casting functions (such as CDate above).